# Loop for and offset

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have maybe simple question. I need to fill some content by some offset. I have loop like this one:

```
for(i=0;i<=459; i++)
{
 document.getElementById("someElement").style.top = someFunction(i);
}
```

Problem is, variable `i` must be by offset like this `0,46,92,138,184,230,276,322,368,414` and after 10 iteration index change to `1,47,93,139,185 ...` to finish in position 459.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i <= 459; i += 46)`

Comment: still doesn't make sense changing same elment in each iteration of loop

Comment: @charlietfl I think he's trying to animate it or something.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir fine but loop will complete in milliseconds and user will only see final value

Comment: Code does not make since since top will not animate with the for loop.... It will be only the last value since screen will not redraw in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested loops, where the outer loop determines the start of the inner loop and inner loop increments each element as needed.

```js
const testArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < 46; i += 1) {
  for(j = i; j < 459; j += 46) {
    // document.getElementById("someElement").style.top = someFunction(j);
    testArray.push(j);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two nested loops.

```js
var i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode((i + j * 46) + ' '));
    }
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```